# What returns CustInvoiceJour.salesTable

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012

I'm learning to develop dynamics ax 2012 and I need to find the data in salesTable corresponding to a CustInvoiceJour record.

Does the method CustInvoiceJour.salesTable return the whole table or the associated record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns a sales table buffer that has records associated with customer invoice journal.

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the function is tablebuffer as a tablebuffer type salesTable is return from the function as a foreign key relationship is exist between custinvoicejour and salesTable on salesId field.

> SalesTable       salesTable = SalesTable::find(this.SalesId, _update);

salestable buffer is find from custinvoicejour current buffer field value this.salesId which is pass into salestable function find which returns salestable buffer contains field values.

```
SalesTable  salesTable(boolean _update = false)
{
    SalesTable       salesTable = SalesTable::find(this.SalesId, _update);
    SalesTableDelete salesTableDelete;
    SalesTable_RU salesTableRU;

    if (!salesTable && this.SalesId && this.SalesType != SalesType::Journal)
    {
        salesTableDelete = SalesTableDelete::find(this.SalesId);
        if (salesTableDelete.SalesTable)
        {
            [salesTable] = salesTableDelete.SalesTable;
            salesTableRU = SalesTable_RU::findBySalesTable(salesTable.RecId);
            salesTable.packSalesTable_RU(salesTableRU);
        }
    }

    return salesTable;
}
```